# How to send email in android using javamail API

Tags: android, email

I want to send an email in android app without using email client(without user interaction). I have code and I tried it in my app. But when I tried to run, it showed a notification "Message sent". But I did not receive any email from the particular id which I mentioned in the code. I did not get any error or warnings too. Please anyone help me to get out of this problem. Thanks

**Here is my code**

```
    //Import files

    public class SendReport extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button;
    EditText editText, editText2;
    String recipient;
    Session session = null;
    ProgressDialog pdialog = null;
    Context context = null;
    String textmessage = null;
    String username = "sender@gmail.com";
    String password = "senderpassword";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_report);
        context = this;
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        recipient = editText.getText().toString();
        textmessage = editText2.getText().toString();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
            }
        });
        pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Sending Mail...", true);
        RetrieveFeedTask task = new RetrieveFeedTask();
        task.execute();
    }

 class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

           try
           {

               MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
               message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("anithabadhu@gmail.com"));
               message.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
               message.setContent(textmessage,"text/html; charset=utf-8");
               Transport.send(message);
           }

           catch(MessagingException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           catch(Exception e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           return null;
       }
        protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
              pdialog.dismiss();
              editText2.setText("");
              editText.setText("");
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem some months ago.

You have to allowing less secure apps to access your google account.

Change it [here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

Now your email must be correctly sent ;)

More information : https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Hey man...thanks ..i have done. now am able to send mail. But am having another issue. I have hard coded my mail id and password. but it should not be the case. How can i do this task? do you have any idea??

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a security expert but [this link](http://codetalk.de/?p=86) may help you.

Comment: Thank you..let me try it..:)